# How do I go about configuring an IBM WebSphere application to utilise Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-active-directory, authorization, websphere

So, I am currently playing around with Azure and I wish to integrate IBM WebSphere and Azure Active Directory.

Now, I have tried to do so using LDAP, but AAD doesn't seem to support it directly - which is understandable as it's a legacy auth protocol, and in my reading I've seen that it is only really an option for on-prem AD.

This means I'm now scouring the internet trying to find a method for SAML or OAuth but with little success. If anyone has any guidance, it would be really appreciated.

Cheers

[image]

Comment: Oh and the WebSphere Application itself is the IBM WebSphere service available on the Azure marketplace, if that is helpful information

Answer (score 2):

You can try with [Setting up Azure as an OIDC OP for WebSphere Application Server and Liberty clients](https://github.com/WASdev/azure.sso.setup/blob/main/azureOidc.md) for how to configure Microsoft AAD as your OpenID Connect provider (OP) for the WebSphere Application Server traditional relying party (RP).

Besides, here is another related blog [Securing Open Liberty applications with Azure Active Directory via OpenID Connect](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/opensource/2020/08/10/securing-open-liberty-applications-azure-active-directory-openid-connect/) we published before. Feel free to fill out the [survey](https://aka.ms/ibm-stack-migration-survey) to work with us and get free Microsoft help for your WebSphere Traditional, WebSphere Liberty, and Open Liberty migration to Azure.